# Find a median among the nearest values using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of data which consists of periodically collected values. I want to calculate a median using 2 left and right neighbors of a current value for each element of set.

For example, the set is:

```
21
22
23
-10
20
22
19
21
100
20
```

For the first value we pick `21`, `22`, `23` which median is `22`. So for `21` we have `22`. For `-10` we have `22`, `23`, `-10`, `20`, `22`. Median is `22`.

I use this method to get rid of "deviant" values which are abnormal for this set.

I guess I should somehow use `median` analytic function. Something like that:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT median(d.value)
          FROM my_set d
         WHERE d.key_val = s.key_val
           AND d.order_value BETWEEN s.order_value - 2 AND s.order_value + 2) median_val
      ,s.key_val
      ,s.order_value
  FROM my_set s
```

I would be happy to see any other approaches or some improved approaches to solve this question.

Comment: How about disregarding new values that differ more than a plausible amount of X from the previous value?

Comment: If those values are temperatures, you may determine it's not plausible for the temperature to change by more than, say 5 degrees C between two measurements.

Comment: @Roman . . . Your method might be the simplest solution.  Oracle doesn't support `MEDIAN()` or `PERCENTILE_<DISC/CONT>()` with `ORDER BY` in the partitioning clause.

Comment: @JimmyB nope, actually it's a size increase of a table in a database. Sometimes we clean tables or insert extra data so these operations shouldn't affect the whole picture of table growth.So there's no `plausible` amount preset and that's why I want to calculate it and then check if new value is in a "valid" range.

Comment: Ok. How about calculating the mean and e.g. the standard deviation and disregarding values that lie outside e.g. mean +/- 2*std.dev.? It would help if you could create a histogram of the values to see if they follow a certain distribution, e.g. [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). On the other hand, if *every* value occurs with equal frequency there's not much you can do.

Comment: By "using 2 left and right neighbors" you mean the four values that surround the current one according to a certain ordering? A "set" does not define an order of values, so you should specify what you define as "neighbors".

Comment: @jimmyb yes, I want to use `mean and std deviation` but first I have to "clean" my set of deviant values. After cleaning I would use this approach

Comment: @JimmyB neighbors are 2 values before, the value I calculate median for and 2 values after. "Neighboring" comes out of `order_value` which is a row number inside of current dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify anything about your table structure so I'm just guessing from your SQL what fields there are and what they're supposed to mean, but consider an attempt like this one:

```
SELECT s1.key_val, s1.order_value, s1.value, MEDIAN(s2.value) as med
FROM my_set s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_set s2
  ON s2.key_val = s1.key_val
  AND (s1.order_value - 2) <= s2.order_value
  AND s2.order_value       <= (s1.order_value + 2)
GROUP BY s1.key_val, s1.order_value, s1.value
```

Comment: Looks like it would be the simpliest way without doing analytics